# IDE for C application development that you admire most

Tags: c, ide

I am looking for a good Integrated development environment for developing applictaions in C language for both windows and linux.

IDE should have:

- good interface,
- easy file management,
- auto filling and
- any advanced options.

Tell me which IDE you most admire for these tasks

1. For general PC application development
2. For embedded application development in C

If you think it is more specific question then you may also take it as a general case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget source control integration!

Answer (score 8):

For general PC development - Microsoft Visual Studio + [VisualAssist](http://www.wholetomato.com/)

For large-scale development you can hardly find anything better than [Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/)

If you need a cross-platform IDE have a look at [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)

Comment: Second Source Insight. Excellent, if ugly, IDE.

Comment: yep ugly but very powerful, I just don't know any other IDE that can candle multi-millions LOC C/C++ projects

Comment: Second Visual Studio. Haven't seen any multi-million LOC projects though. :P

Comment: I was involved in development of Motorola P2k operating system - few millions LOC, I just don't know how to handle project of this size without Source Insight (though, someone used vim for that :) )

Comment: yep vim and makefiles best choice :) number of LOC unlimited :)

Answer (score 1):

For both purposes I'd suggest [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd describe Visual Studio as the most feature rich and comfortable place to be when writing and debugging code, but it has a narrow target audience - Windows developers.

As others have said, Eclipse is probably your best bet, The [large array of available plugins come in handy too](http://www.eclipse-plugins.info/eclipse/plugins.jsp).  For example, if you want to move to a new source code repository, the chances are there's an Eclipse plugin already written for it.  You don't have that luxury with most other IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Well when I'm working with C I use [Vim](http://www.vim.org), with the right plugins I find it to be the best IDE for C around. It takes a little bit of practice to get used to it but once you do you'll just be flying around your files.

Comment: Could you list some plug-ins you find most useful?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) on OS X which is more a very featurefull text editor, I'd say NetBeans or Eclipse.

EDIT: yes, if you have a mac, you can do PC development with VMWare/Paralles as easily as you would in a "real" PC and you get OS X as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Eclipse is the best choice.
[Eclipse page](http://www.eclipse.org)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), it's pretty good, does C, and is available for Windows and Linux as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it was developed for JAVA first, I like the [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) IDE because it has some nice features and it [knows about C](http://www.netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html), too.

CVS/SVN Plugins are available.

Comment: NEtBeans would be sooooo much better if it wasn't soooooo slow

Comment: It got a little better (especially the startup) with Version 6.5

Comment: @Alex Baranosky: Is "speed" the only reason why people prefer Eclipse over NetBeans? I have been using NetBeans for long, and I am surprised to find (for example on this particular question) that people only recommend Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[SlickEdit](http://slickedit.com) is nice cross-platform IDE with autocomplition, macroses, various text editors emulation mode, refactoring capabilities etc... Commercial though.

Answer (score 0):

There's some good advice on C IDEs here as well: [C on Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605/c-on-visual-studio)

I asked about using C in Visual Studio but the answers contain suggestions on a variety of IDEs