# C Struct typdef malloc assignment

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to use struct called `BankAccount` it takes char array of name 50 letters long , `int ID`, and `double balance`. I am trying to use `malloc()` to put it to pointer but i get this

```
error : void can not be assigned to an entity of type BankAccount.
```

```c
typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int ID;
    double balance;
} BankAccount;

FILE *fp;
BankAccount *accounts = 0;
int accountSize = 0;
// I init like this in main function

accounts = malloc(accountSize * sizeof(*accounts));



void ReadAccountData(BankAccount *accounts, FILE *fp, int arraySize)
{
int i = 0;
while (!feof && i < arraySize) {
    fread(&accounts, sizeof(accounts), i, fp);
    i++;
 }

  }
```

Comment: Use a C compiler, not a C++ compiler!

Comment: So, `accountSize = 0`?

Comment: @iharob: Yes, that is another problem. But not the cause of the error message.

Comment: @Olaf the only possible cause is clear in your first comment.

Comment: @iharob: Every dog has its day ;-)

Comment: this does not work at all.

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: `while(!feof())` **has never worked and never will**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C language, you need to use C compiler for your code. The compiler you are using now looks like C++ compiler, which requires casting `void *` to destined type. In C you shouldn't do this, as pointed out by @Olaf ([Why you can't cast `void *` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)).

How to change compilator? It depends on IDE and operating system, that you are using, this needs to be specified before I can give any more details.

If you want to use C++ you have few options:

1. Use `malloc`, but cast return value:

   ```
   accounts = static_cast<BankAccount *>(
                  malloc(accountSize * sizeof(BankAccount)));
   ```
2. Use dynamic allocation dedicated for `C++` and treat `BankAccount` as `C++` structure(you can add constructors, destructors, methods etc.):

   ```
   accounts = new BankAccount[accountSize];
   ```

Comment: I am using visual studio how would i go about using a c compiler?

Comment: You can try this answer : [C on Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4177088/2641513)

Answer (score -2):

Should be like this:

```
accounts = (BankAccount *)malloc(accountSize * sizeof(BankAccount));
```

Comment: Do not cast `void *` in C!

Comment: If the OP intended to use c++ it should be `static_cast<BankAccount *>(malloc(...))` and more likely, `BankAccount` could have a constructor, so `new BankAccount[accountSize]`.

Comment: in C we don't have constructor. But still I don't get way @Olaf says my answer is incorrect.

Comment: [You don't cast `void *` in c, that's it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495).

Comment: @iharob: Did not say to use a constructor in C, but in case he confuses C with C++ to use one for the class. But as this seems to be C code: `malloc` & friends return `void *`. And you should not cast this to/from another pointer type **in C**. In C++ you have to (but should not use these functions at all).

Comment: @Olaf if you should not cast `void *` from `malloc()` in C,can you give an example for using result of `malloc()`? Because I have always wrote my code like this. I will be happy to learn something new.

Comment: Please read the link @iharob provided. This has been answered here sooooooo many time already. For using the result of `malloc`: `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p); free(p);` So? Note this simply follows from not casting without need **and** exactly knowledege why **and** **all** implications. this is not different from C++ or any other language..

Comment: @Olaf Anyway, this was completely something new for me which differs from what is specified in cplusplus :http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/  And MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: cplusplus is for c plus plus c++, that is different from c. And MSDN us for the windows API mostly, many of the functions at MSDN are not even standard.

Comment: @Afshin In any language you use, typically if you can avoid an explicit cast, avoid it. Imagine if we wrote code like `double d = ...; d = (double)fabs(d);` or even `double x = (double)some_double * (double)2.0;` It can be a source of error and just unnecessary -- harmless at the very best, a source of error and confusion at worst. C++ is a different case since it requires a static cast to cast from void* to some other pointer type. There it's necessary. But if unnecessary, err on the side of leaving the cast out.

Comment: So i should not use afshin solution its dangerous?